# Problems understanding a Ruby example file for Google API Client Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api-ruby-client

I am trying to access Google APIs from my Rails App. 
I understand the basic flow for OAuth2.0 for Web Applications.
And I consider myself having a basic understanding of Ruby and Rails.

Yet, I can't make sense of the example Google shows in the "[API Client Library for Ruby (Alpha)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/aaa_oauth)" Guides.

```
require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'sinatra'
require 'logger'

enable :sessions

def logger; settings.logger end

def calendar; settings.calendar; end

def user_credentials
# Build a per-request oauth credential based on token stored in session
# which allows us to use a shared API client.
  @authorization ||= (
    auth = settings.authorization.dup
    auth.redirect_uri = to('/oauth2callback')
    auth.update_token!(session)
    auth
  )
end

configure do
  log_file = File.open('calendar.log', 'a+')
  log_file.sync = true
  logger = Logger.new(log_file)
  logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

  Google::Apis::ClientOptions.default.application_name = 'Ruby Calendar sample'
  Google::Apis::ClientOptions.default.application_version = '1.0.0'
  calendar_api = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new

  client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
  authorization = client_secrets.to_authorization
  authorization.scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'

  set :authorization, authorization
  set :logger, logger
  set :calendar, calendar_api
end

before do
 # Ensure user has authorized the app
  unless user_credentials.access_token || request.path_info =~ /^\/oauth2/
    redirect to('/oauth2authorize')
  end
end

after do
# Serialize the access/refresh token to the session and credential store.
  session[:access_token] = user_credentials.access_token
  session[:refresh_token] = user_credentials.refresh_token
  session[:expires_in] = user_credentials.expires_in
  session[:issued_at] = user_credentials.issued_at
end

get '/oauth2authorize' do
# Request authorization
  redirect user_credentials.authorization_uri.to_s, 303
end

get '/oauth2callback' do
  # Exchange token
  user_credentials.code = params[:code] if params[:code]
  user_credentials.fetch_access_token!
  redirect to('/')
end

get '/' do
  # Fetch list of events on the user's default calandar
  events = calendar.list_events('primary', options: { authorization: user_credentials })
  [200, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, events.to_h.to_json]
end
```

Of course this looks like Ruby, but I never saw some of the constructs used here, and I am not sure where in a Rails app that code would go.

Is it Ruby? If so, how do I use it?

Comment: yes, this is ruby. You are looking at an example implementation based on sinatra http://www.sinatrarb.com/documentation.html, vanilla functionality without the rails overhead.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Don't get why they use Sinatra as base for a Ruby example. This makes it really difficult for me to understand it.

Comment: You don't explain if you're using OAuth2 for web applications or server to server applications, but I recommend that you use the non-Sinatra examples at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/service-accounts.